# magento 2.1.5 unable to add product getting mysql error

Tags: magento-2.1, product, database

i am getting below error while adding product in magento 2.1.5

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e` WHERE (())
```

> 2 exception(s): Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception):
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1,
>   query was: SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e` WHERE
>   (()) Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '))' at line 1
>
> Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '))' at line 1, query was: SELECT `e`.* FROM
>   `catalog_category_entity` AS `e` WHERE (())

Comment: I would recommend trying to reindex as this usually fixes the majority of database related issues

Answer (score 0):

Just remove an empty `WHERE (())` because it is wrong syntax for MySQL. In case you don't know from where it comes, add more details: when and where that error appears.